# Use Google WebFontLoader to Call Script after Font is Loaded

Tags: javascript, masonry, packery, webfont-loader

I want to use Google's WebFontLoader to call a javascript function after all fonts are loaded.

The script I want to call is Packery and imagesloaded:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.layouter');
var $pckry;
var $pckry = new Packery( container, {
// options
itemSelector: '.item',
gutter: 0,
});
// initialize Packery after all images have loaded
imagesLoaded( container, function() {
$pckry = new Packery( container );
});
```

My problem is that I have no idea of how to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the solution is to link to fontloader, and wrap the javascript to be called after fontloade in the fontloader like this:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js'></script>

    WebFont.load({
        google: {
          families: ['Lato:300','Lato:400', 'Lato:100' ]
        },
    active: function() {

    var container = document.querySelector('.layouter');
    var $pckry;
    var $pckry = new Packery( container, {
    // options
    itemSelector: '.item',
    gutter: 0,
    });
    // initialize Packery after all images have loaded
    imagesLoaded( container, function() {
    $pckry = new Packery( container );
    });


    }

});
```

I havent changed anything to my original script, just added the fontloader arround it, and it works for me.

Comment: Works great! Thank you!